# Apche beam Class Not Found Exception: Jackson

Tags: java, maven, jackson, pom.xml, apache-beam

I was upgrading my apache beam pipeline version **2.27.0** to the latest version **2.41.0**
When I run my pipeline I got this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.Module: com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jsr310.JavaTimeModule Unable to get public no-arg constructor
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:582)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader.getConstructor(ServiceLoader.java:673)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyClassPathLookupIterator.hasNextService(ServiceLoader.java:1233)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyClassPathLookupIterator.hasNext(ServiceLoader.java:1265)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$2.hasNext(ServiceLoader.java:1300)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$3.hasNext(ServiceLoader.java:1385)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.findModules(ObjectMapper.java:982)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.options.PipelineOptionsFactory.<clinit>(PipelineOptionsFactory.java:502)
    at 
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ser/std/ToStringSerializerBase
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1016)
    at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:174)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:800)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:698)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:621)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:579)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:3137)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3342)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:2151)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$1.run(ServiceLoader.java:660)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$1.run(ServiceLoader.java:657)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader.getConstructor(ServiceLoader.java:668)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.ToStringSerializerBase
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    ... 24 more
```

I have included the jackson core dependency but yet same error

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.12.3</version>
        </dependency>
```

**Note that before upgrading the apache beam version the pipeline was running without this dependency**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have solved the problem it is not enough to add `jackson-core` and `jackson-databind` dependencies you need to add `jackson-annotations` also ensure that the version is >= 2.12.0 which includes the **ToStringSerializerBase**:

In your `pom.xml`:

```
<jackson.version>2.13.4</jackson.version>
```

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
     <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
     <version>${jackson.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
     <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
     <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
     <version>${jackson.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
     <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
     <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
     <version>${jackson.version}</version>
</dependency>
```